# $_POST Returning "Undefined index"

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, post

I know this question has been asked a lot, but none of the solutions work for me!

**Please read the edit below first!**

I'm relatively new to PHP, and I am creating a simple contact form:

**HTML**:

```
<form action="contactUsSuccess.php" id="contactForm" method="post" name="contactForm" onsubmit="return validateContactUs();">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="name" maxlength="70" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="email" maxlength="255" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <textarea id="message" maxlength="5000" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="submitArea">
                <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Send">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**PHP**, which is on *another page*.

```
<?php
    $success = false;

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $to = "----@gmail.com";
    $subject = "New Contact Message - ----";
    $messageMail = "From: " . $name . "(" . $email . ")" . " | Message: " . $message;
    $header = "From: ----@gmail.com";

    if(mail($to, $subject, $messageMail, $header)) {
        $success = true;
    }
?>
```

My error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in Z:\Documents\Workspace\----\help\contactUsSuccess.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: email in Z:\Documents\Workspace\----\help\contactUsSuccess.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: message in Z:\Documents\Workspace\----\help\contactUsSuccess.php on line 8
```

As you may be able to see, my form's `onsubmit` executes JavaScript, which just returns true or false.  If you think for any reason that may be the reason why this isn't working, just ask.

Also, I've tried the same PHP code that is shown above and put it in the same file as the original HTML (and also surrounding it with `isset` if statements... no luck.

Oh, and the email still sends... it just sends:

> From: () | Message:

**Edit:** So it was the JavaScript!  Here is the main part of it:

```
if (!(nameLen > 0 && nameLen <= 70 && emailLen > 0 && emailLen <= 255 && messageLen > 0 && messageLen <= 5000)) {
        cont = false;
    } else {
        name.disabled = "true";
        email.disabled = "true";
        message.disabled = "true";
        document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = "true";
    }

    if (cont) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I removed the 3 `--.disabled = "true";`, it worked!  However, I did have them in there for a reason.  Is there an alternative?  I guess this is what I'm asking for now...

Comment: Does it work when you take out the validation function in the submit event? (I.e. the JavaScript)

Comment: you need to check first that weather the post variable is set or not

Comment: Are you sure you used isset method as said by you in all the $_POST variables?

Comment: Try just var_dump($_POST) in your php file to see if any form data is getting posted on to that page or not. At times, the form data doesn't get posted due to some issue in configuration. It happened with one of my colleagues around a year back.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 - You are correct, however I can't get rid of all of it.  Please read my latest edit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must check if all the variables name, email, message have values, for example:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message']))
```

and if yes, then send the email. Your error is saying that there's no value in those variables. Problem may be even in yout javascript validation, so try to put it away and then check.

**EDIT AFTER QUESTION EDIT:**

Try this:

```
<script>
function validate(form) {
fail = validateName(form.name.value)
fail += validateEmail(form.email.value)
fail += validateMessage(form.message.value)
if (fail == "") return true
  else { alert(fail); return false }
}

function validateName(field) {
if (field == "") return "No Username was entered.\n"
else if (field.length < 5)
    return "Usernames must be at least 5 characters.\n"
else if (field.length > 15)
    return "Usernames must be shorter than 15 characters.\n"
return ""
 </script>
```

Comment: or you may try to assign all the variables empty string, for example, `$name = $email = $message = ""` but if you send form without values it will send empty email

Comment: The page that is processing the form data will *only* be visited when the form has been submitted, 100% of the time.  Also, I have already tried the `isset` stuff... no luck.  Please read my latest edit, thanks!

Comment: i updated my answer, there's one way how to validate it...the function is easy, just to the form tag add `onSubmit="return validate(this)"` and when you press submit it will run function validate(form)...it then check now just length of name, but you can do email and message the same way...if validation is without problem it return true and can be validated, if no it will alert error, hope it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Check your button to make sure it has the name attribute:

```
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" name="yourname" value="Send">

<?php
if (isset($_POST['yourname'])) {
    /*do some codes here*/
} else {
    /**/
}
?>
```